# Tornado: pattern for Flask's flashed messages

Tags: python, flask, tornado

In `Flask`, flashing messages on redirect is done using the `flash` function in the view + `{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}` in the template. Tornado doesn't seem to have anything like that built in (which is fine with me, fwiw).

Only replacement I've seen so far looks like this (part of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/4771570)):

```
class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        errormessage = self.get_argument("error", default="")
        self.render("login.html", errormessage = errormessage)

    def post(self):
        ...(code)...
        if not auth:
            error_msg = u"?error=" + tornado.escape.url_escape("Login incorrect")
            self.redirect(u"/auth/login/" + error_msg)
```

And then in the template:

```
 <span class="errormessage">{{errormessage}}</span>
```

Is there a cleaner pattern?

(I can see how one could do multiple messages with this pattern, and a couple ways of cleaning it up, but that's not what I'm asking.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flask's flash by default uses cookies, so a direct translation would be to use `self.set_secure_cookie("flash", message)` to set a message and `self.get_secure_cookie("flash"); self.clear_cookie("flash")` to read it back.